# Netezza SQL function

Tags: netezza

I want to select data as per below criteria in Netezza.
can someone help me to write the sql.

```
Case 1: Unique ID has 2 "."s 
Deal ID  = Parse  from UNIQ_ID. Pos 1 to first "."
E.g. 
Unique ID = 0000149844.FXFWD.COIBI_I
Deal ID = 0000149844

Case 2: Unique ID has 1 "."s 
Deal ID  = Parse  from UNIQ_ID. First "." to end
E.g
Unique ID = 25808.1234140AT`enter code here`
Deal ID = 1234140AT
```

Comment: This is not the site to ask people to write code for you. Instead, try to write it yourself, and then ask for help when you get stuck. Make sure to include the code that you've tried.

Comment: I tried below code but it only works for case1. i'm not able to get code for both case in 1 sql                                                                                  select trim(substring('0000157704.FXSPOT.COIBI_I',1,(instr('0000157704.FXSPOT.COIBI_I','.') - 1 ) )) ABC from dual;

Answer (score 0):

Use "position" function of Netezza to determine the position of ".", Make use of this output in "substr" function to extract required fields.

For Case 1 :

```
select substr('0000149844.FXFWD.COIBI_I',1,(position('.' in '0000149844.FXFWD.COIBI_I') - 1));
```

For Case 2 :

```
select substr('25808.1234140AT',(position('.' in '25808.1234140AT') + 1));
```